# Can an actor have a direct relationship to an use-case that starts after another use-case succeeded?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I want to write an application that can upload a file, validate that file, convert it and return the file in the new format.

The user has to upload a file. The next step is to choose a template that the system has to use for validation. This second step will only be available if the upload succeeded. Third step is to choose an output format. There is also the option to create a new output format.

All 4 steps are done by the user. But each step can only start if the step before has succeeded. In my mind the actor needs relations(lines) to all the use-cases or all the relations are extended?

Does my diagram display correctly what I'm describing?

[image: Use-case-diagram image]

Comment: You are trying to do an Activity Diagram using Use Case elements. Try to use the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is just ONE use case: `Convert file` and the bubbles are actions inside of the "Sunny day" Activity/Scenario which is inside the use case.